# how to change Avada theme copyright text

Tags: wordpress

I have developed my site using avada WP theme but a few hours ago my Avada Theme Options page stopped loading. I have read a lot of articles but none made it work. The reason why i wanted to access the theme options is to change my copyright text. In which .php file is the copyright text info stored may be i can make changes from the file itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copyright text is displayed via the footer.php file.  If you want to manually remove it then copy the `footer.php` file to your child theme folder and delete the code shown below.  Alternatively, you could update the meta field 'pyre_display_copyright' for the post id `$c_page_id` in the database and set it to the value `'no'`.  Another option would be to remove the hook `avada_render_footer_copyright_notice` which will still leave some of the copyright footer HTML present.

```
<?php
/**
 * Check if the footer copyright area should be displayed.
 */
$display_copyright = get_post_meta( $c_page_id, 'pyre_display_copyright', true );
?>
<?php if ( ( Avada()->settings->get( 'footer_copyright' ) && 'no' !== $display_copyright ) || ( ! Avada()->settings->get( 'footer_copyright' ) && 'yes' === $display_copyright ) ) : ?>
    <?php $footer_copyright_center_class = ( Avada()->settings->get( 'footer_copyright_center_content' ) ) ? ' fusion-footer-copyright-center' : ''; ?>

    <footer id="footer" class="fusion-footer-copyright-area<?php echo esc_attr( $footer_copyright_center_class ); ?>">
        <div class="fusion-row">
            <div class="fusion-copyright-content">

                <?php
                /**
                 * Footer Content (Copyright area) avada_footer_copyright_content hook.
                 *
                 * @hooked avada_render_footer_copyright_notice - 10 (outputs the HTML for the Theme Options footer copyright text)
                 * @hooked avada_render_footer_social_icons - 15 (outputs the HTML for the footer social icons)..
                 */
                do_action( 'avada_footer_copyright_content' );
                ?>

            </div> <!-- fusion-fusion-copyright-content -->
        </div> <!-- fusion-row -->
    </footer> <!-- #footer -->
<?php endif; // End footer copyright area check. ?>
```

If you want to modify the copyright text then use this code. Place it in your `functions.php` file of your child theme.

```
add_action( 'avada_footer_copyright_content', 'modify_avada_footer_copyright_content' );

function modify_avada_footer_copyright_content() {
    echo 'This is my copyright text';
}
```

Comment: i have avada version 5.2.2 and i cant find the file where i can update the text on the copyright. I am not trying to disable copyright but update

Comment: This is the file to do that.  If you can't access the options anymore then use the hook avada_footer_copyright_content to output your copyright notice.  I'll update my answer to show this.

Comment: I have tried to edit the functions.php file of the child theme but now both the copyright text generated by the avada theme appears as well as the one I have added to the file. Where exactly is this text stored in the avada theme? cant i change it manually from there?

Comment: It's stored in the database which I have explained in my answer.

Answer (score 10):

For Avada (5.7.2): On the left-hand side under Avada, you'll find theme options. This is where you normally go to change layout, colors, typography, etc. You'll find Footer near the top, under sliding bar. At the bottom of Footer Content, you'll see whatever it is that you have/had for Copyright.
TL;DR: Avada-> Theme Options-> Footer-> Footer Content

Answer (score 3):

I hope this can help you. I assume, that you are using the latest version of the Avada theme.

In your Dashboard options on the left-hand side, simply go to "Appearance / Theme Options / Footer" and then scroll down to "Copyright Options" whereby you will be able to uncheck the box against "Copyright Bar".

Please follow our article on this issue, which guides you on how to make custom css changes like those – yourself, in the future. http://theme-fusion.com/knowledgebase/how-to-make-custom-css-changes/

Comment: the main reason of asking the question is that the Appearance / Theme Options /  links leads to a blank page

Comment: So, you can solve the issue by Footer.php Code method. If your theme does not have the option to remove or modify footer credits from WordPress admin, then your only option is to edit the footer.php code.

You can find this file in your /wp-content/themes/yourtheme/footer.php